# How to make labels go next to input boxes in CSS

Tags: css

I have a form on my website in which I have aligned the input box to the right, to make the form neat and orderly.

However any time I set the form to

```
input[type=text]{align:right}
```

the labels all bunch up at the top of the form. Problem on JSfiddle..:

http://jsfiddle.net/4hX4g/

If anyone knows how to fix this annoying problem or can point me in the right direction, please do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Simply define the display as `inline-block`, and define a `width` for the `label`:

```
label, input[type=text] {
    display: inline-block;
}

label {
    width: 10em;
    /* other CSS unchanged */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4hX4g/1/).

The use of `inline-block` is to allow the elements to display `inline` (so next to each other on the same line), but *also* to allow them to have a defined with. An `input` is, typically, `inline-block` by default, so you can, similarly, get away with simply adding the following two lines to the `label` declaration:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    /* other CSS unchanged */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4hX4g/2/).

Retaining the above CSS, you could also remove the presentational `<br />` tags, and simply use CSS:

```
label, input {
    float: left;
}

input[type=text] + label {
    clear: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4hX4g/5/).

Note, also, that the `input` element is a void/empty element; and is self-closing: `<input />`, *not* `<input></input>`, the final demo corrects the HTML, the first two left it uncorrected (and, honestly, unnoticed).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to place this fields in `divs`.

[Here is an working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4hX4g/4/)